# Html Textarea field belonging to multiple forms

Tags: html, forms, attributes, textarea

For a `textarea` field you can use the form attribute to specify a form with an id that the field belongs to. Like this:

```
<textarea name="test" form="form1">
```

Now what I want to do is that there are two forms with the ids form1 and form2. I have no idea how multiple values in html look like.

This doesn't work:

```
<textarea name="test" form="form1" form="form2">
```

This neither:

```
<textarea name="test" form="form1 form2">
```

This neither:

```
<textarea name="test" form="form1, form2">
```

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to accomplish here. If you could add some more details about the form(s) you'r creating that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible for a control to belong to multiple forms.

Comment: @devGeek — W3Schools is wrong (again… W3Schools is *awful*). The form attribute allows an input to be associated with a single form based on the id of the form instead of the form being an ancestor of the control. See [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-formelements-form). (And if you have an answer, you can give it as an *answer* rather than as a comment on an existing answer).